# (Python 3.7) How can i print messages characters with a delay between them using tkinter?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, sleep

First of all i'm new to python and coding

I want to do something pretty simple with **tkinter**, when you hit a button it show you a text, like in old games, letter by letter with a little delay between each characters

I can't find a way to make the delay between characters, i've tried **time.sleep** with a loop but the text is shown at the end of the loop

I've seen the **after** function but i don't know how to use it neither i understand how it works

Should i use **sleep** or **after** ? And how should i use them to make it work ?

Btw if you have any tips or advices about the code tell me

```
    #MainFrame
root.title("Project")
root.geometry('400x400')
root.configure(bg="plum1")
    #Frame
BlackBorder=Frame(root,width=400,height=300,bg='Black')
BlackBorder.place(x=0,y=80)
TxtFrame=Frame(BlackBorder,width=370,height=270,bg='lavender')
TxtFrame.place(x=15,y=15)
    #Display
Cunter=Text(root,width=24,height=1,bg='lavender',font='Fixedsys')
Cunter.place(x=100,y=22)
Cunter.insert(END, str(len(LoList))+" Résultats Différents")


#defTxt
def LoMsg(self):
    self=Text(TxtFrame,wrap='word',borderwidth=0,width=35,height=10,bg='lavender',font='Fixedsys')
    self.place(x=50,y=100)
    LoTxt=str(LovList[randrange(len(LovList))])
    LoNum=0
    while LoNum!=len(LoTxt):
        self.insert(END,LoTxt[LoNum])
        sleep(0.1)
        LoNum+=1

    #Button
buttonMain=Button(root,width=9,height=3,bg='thistle2',text="Try me",font='Fixedsys')
buttonMain.place(x=5,y=5)
#ButtonEvent
buttonMain.bind('<1>', LoMsg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example to highlight the usage of the `after(ms, callback)` method to get your desired result (adjust the `ms` in the after method accordingly):

```
import tkinter as Tk

def insert():
    global LoNum
    text.insert(Tk.END, word[LoNum])
    LoNum += 1
    if LoNum != len(word):
        root.after(300, insert)
    else:
        return

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x200')

LoNum = 0
word = [x for x in 'abcdefg'] # get the word to a list format
text = Tk.Text(root, wrap='word', borderwidth=0, width=35, height=10, bg='lavender')
text.pack()

Tk.Button(root, text='Try Me', width=9, height=3, bg='thistle2', command=insert).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First, the else block can be removed inside `insert()`.  Second, if `Try Me` button is clicked the second time, there will be error as `LoNum` is not reset.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python and coding!  There's a few things I want to address before I answer your question:

1. It is helpful if you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking your question.  I can't really see what the issue in your code is because there's so much happening and I can't run it on my computer because there are parts missing. For example, `LoList` is undefined and there are no `import` statements.)
2. PEP8 has a huge list of suggestions on how to style your code - too much to read all at once.  But I'd like to draw your attention to [Function and Variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), which suggests that variables and functions use all lowercase, with words separated by underscores.  Usually [Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) start with a capital letter.  So a lot of your variables and functions look like classes to me.

To answer your question, I think that using `time.sleep()` would work.  Here's a simple example that runs in a console that might help you figure out how to use it:

```
import time
text = "I've been awaiting your arrival..."
for char in text:
    # end='' will prevent each letter from getting its own line on the console
    # flush=True will make sure that the character is printed right away in the console
    print(char, end='', flush=True) 
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: you should never call `time.sleep` in the main thread of the GUI. It prevents the GUI from being able to process events, including events such as requests to resize the window, redraw the window, etc.

Comment: OP is already using `time.sleep`, so what is the difference between your solution and OP?  The issue of OP is that the text is not shown character by character as expected.